# How to make play button disabled after the animation is finished?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I have this problem: I have two buttons `btStop` and `btRace` . BtPlays clicks all the buttons bt1 and all my cars are driving at the same time. BtStop works exactly the same but it stops the animation. My problem is, that when I once click btRace and animation is done I cannot click it again unless I click btStop, which is misleading because animation is already stopped.

Is there a way to make btPlay active again after the animation is finished?

I have long code so I am pasting showButtons method

```js
showButtons(bt1, bt2, img, editingCarId) {
  let playBts = document.querySelectorAll('.play')
  function animation(img) {
    let status = 'started';
    let aPICallCarEngineState = new APICallCarEngineState(editingCarId, status);
    aPICallCarEngineState.processRequestJSON((res) => {
      //    let resStr = JSON.stringify(res);
      // console.log('I got ' + res)
      res.velocity = res.velocity * 0.01
      //    res.distance = res.distance * 0.001
      res.distance = 500;
      // ===========Animation===================
      img.style.animation = `car_move ${res.velocity}s ease-in`
    })
  }
  //================Stop Animation===============
  function stopAnimation() {
    img.style.animation = 'none'
    console.log(bt2 + 'stopp')
  }
  bt1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    animation(img)
  });
  bt2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    stopAnimation()
  })
  //=================Button start all animations ====================
  this.btRace.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bt1.click();
  })
  //=================Button stop all animations ====================
  this.btStop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bt2.click();
  })
}


invoke:
  constructor:
  this.table.appendTableHeadButton('RACE!')
this.table.appendTableHeadButtonStop('stop')

Buttoncreator:
  appendTableHeadButtonStop(text) {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    this.btStop = document.createElement('button');
    this.btStop.innerText = text;
    this.btStop.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    td.appendChild(this.btStop);
    let bt = this.btStop;
    this.headeRow.appendChild(td);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 showButtons(bt1, bt2, img, editingCarId) {
  let playBts = document.querySelectorAll('.play')
  let isAnimating = false;

  function animation(img) {
    isAnimating = true;
    btRace.disabled = true;

    let status = 'started';
    let aPICallCarEngineState = new APICallCarEngineState(editingCarId, status);
    aPICallCarEngineState.processRequestJSON((res) => {
      //    let resStr = JSON.stringify(res);
      // console.log('I got ' + res)
      res.velocity = res.velocity * 0.01
      //    res.distance = res.distance * 0.001
      res.distance = 500;
      // ===========Animation===================
      img.style.animation = `car_move ${res.velocity}s ease-in`

      img.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
        isAnimating = false;
        btRace.disabled = false;
      });
    });
  }

  //================Stop Animation===============
  function stopAnimation() {
    isAnimating = false;
    btRace.disabled = false;
    img.style.animation = 'none'
    console.log(bt2 + 'stopp')
  }

  bt1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    animation(img)
  });

  bt2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    stopAnimation()
  });

  //=================Button start all animations ====================
  this.btRace.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bt1.click();
  });

  //=================Button stop all animations ====================
  this.btStop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    bt2.click();
  });
}
```

I am adding a flag to check the state of animation, and then toggle `disabled` property of `btRace` button respectively.